# Check which parameters were passed when a function is called

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am unit testing a method where I do two different things with same parameter.I want to check which parameters are passed in both the statements. and either they are same.

**Method I am testing**

```
 doWork(value: boolean) {
   if (value) {
      add(value);
    } else {
      delete(value);
   }
  }
```

I know I can test with "toHaveBeenCalledWith" for a specific value.

But here I would like to test where it's the same for **add** and for **delete**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can take advantage of `callFake` on Jasmine. `callFake` calls the function you supply every time that function is called.

Something like this.

```
it('should call add and delete with the same value', () => {
  const addParameter;
  const deleteParameter;
  spyOn(component, 'add').and.callFake(value => addParameter = value);
  spyOn(component, 'delete').and.callFake(value => deleteParamter = value);
  component.add(5);
  component.delete(5);
  expect(addParameter).toBe(deleteParameter);
});
```

Of course that is a contrived example but something like that should get you going. I also wrote it as if you were using Angular 2+.